# DB2 JDBC PreparedStatement Execute error "Decfloat conversion requires JDK1.5 null"

Tags: java, jdbc, db2

I am trying to run a small update query on a DB2 table using JAVA JDBC. I get this error when I use prepared statement binding variable to pass values. The column I am trying to update is declared as DECIMAL(13,2). Please someone guide me how to resolve this.

DB2 version 11.1
Java version 8
Latest JDBC driver downloaded from IBM website
Windows

```
String query="update ALLOC_SUM set stat_amt=? where cost_cntr=50";
PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(query);
BigDecimal bd=new BigDecimal("2.54");
stmt.setBigDecimal(1, bd);
stmt.executeUpdate();
```

**Exception stacktrace**

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][1037][11192][3.71.22] Exception occurred during Decimal floating point conversion.  See attached Throwable for details. ERRORCODE=-4220, SQLSTATE=null
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:797)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:66)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.gd.a(gd.java:98)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.eb.b(eb.java:1903)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.hb.a(hb.java:1578)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.hb.a(hb.java:1362)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.hb.a(hb.java:1350)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.hb.a(hb.java:1276)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.hb.a(hb.java:876)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.hb.a(hb.java:221)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.wb.a(wb.java:177)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hp.a(hp.java:3417)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hp.a(hp.java:4253)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hp.b(hp.java:4062)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hp.jc(hp.java:792)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hp.executeUpdate(hp.java:770)
    at net.abcbs.cost.batch.job.TestJobImpl.run(TestJobImpl.java:45)
    at net.abcbs.cost.batch.deploy.BatchJobAdapter.execute(BatchJobAdapter.java:18)
    at net.abcbs.cost.batch.deploy.UnitTestJobRunner.main(UnitTestJobRunner.java:11)
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.ConversionException: [jcc][converters][606][10995]Decfloat conversion requires JDK1.5 null
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.e.a(e.java:356)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.e.b(e.java:217)
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.t4.eb.b(eb.java:1899)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.ibm.db2.jcc.a.e.a(e.java:334)
    ... 17 more
```

Comment: You are using the GA (general availability = fixpack 0 ) driver which is always a mistake. This identifies as `[3.71.22]` . At todays date the current version is 3.72.52, so consider downloading and applying fixpack 4.   If this is a new installation, consider using the Type-4 driver by ensuring that the *first* db2 driver that is on the CLASSPATH is dbcjcc4.jar (and not db2jcc.jar). You get more precise messages from the Type-4 driver usually.

Comment: Mao, thanks for the reply. I mentioned the column type in the question. DECIMAL (13,2)

Comment: @mao 

They are both Type-4 drivers. db2jcc.jar is JDBC 3.0-compliant, and db2jcc4.jar - JDBC 4.0-compliant.

Comment: @Venkatesh Are you sure that you really use java 1.8 on your client? What's the output of the following command where you run your java program? `java -version`

Comment: :) I am sure Mark that we use Java 8 across the board. I removed the libraries from build path and re added and all of a sudden it works. I don't know what happened.